# Ruby on Rails 3: HABTM association does not update join-table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I'm desperately trying to get a HABTM association working. I have a customers database in which every customer can have many contacts. From the customers "show" view, I want to have a link to add a new contact to that selected customer.

So far, I have the following data:

models/customer.rb:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

models/contact.rb:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :customers
end
```

views/customers/show.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'Add new contact', new_customer_contact_path(@customer) %>
```

I also have three tables:

```
customers (id, name)
contacts (id, name)
contacts_customers (contact_id, customer_id)  <- the join-table
```

Now when I click on the "add new contact"-link, I get to a "new customer" page, it even correctly assigns the customer_id, but when I click on "save" after filling in the contact-information, the contact is created, but the join-table (contacts_customers) is not updated. As a result, the newly created contact is not "connected" to the customer.

I already browsed the net for about two hours on this one and cannot help myself. I'd be more than happy if somebody could point me in the right direction!

Thanks!

[Edit: Updated details]
Here's which parameters get passed over once I click on the "new contact" link on my "show.html.erb" view

```
Started GET "/customers/260/contacts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-18 08:21:28
  Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"customer_id"=>"260"}
  Customer Load (0.0ms) SELECT 'customers'.* FROM 'customers' WHERE 'customers'.'id' = 260 LIMIT 1
  Rendered contacts/_form.html.erb (9.0ms)
  Rendered contacts/new.html within layouts/application (13.0ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 343 ms (Views: 26.0ms  | ActiveRecord: 299.0ms)
```

As you can see, the customer_id (it is 260 in my example) should be passed over to the new contact controller.
When I click on "save" however which starts the POST-request to actually create the database entries, the customer_id
is lost and only the contact table is updated:

```
Started POST "/contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-18 08:28:00 +0100
  Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Ô£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"jWMlruMezFGOy1j7vTbE9OcL8VareGUXS1AprBpNhGA=", "contact"=>{"anrede"=>"", "name"=>"Test", "position"=>"", "telefon"=>"", "mobil"=>"", "fax"=>"", "email"=>"", "sonstiges"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Contact"}
  BEGIN SQL (0.0ms)
  INSERT INTO `contacts` (`anrede`, `email`, `fax`, `mobil`, `name`, `position`, `sonstiges`, `telefon`) VALUES ('', '', '', '', 'Test', '', '', '') (113.0ms)
  COMMIT
  Redirected to http://localhost:3000/contacts/626
  Completed 302 Found in 174ms
```

I'm not sure if it's of any help, but just in case. My routes are set up like this:

```
resources :contacts
resources :customers do
  resources :contacts
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to check is if you defined any attributes using the macro attr_accessible. For more info look this below link.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#label-Saving.

I would suggest to test the params hash in the console. You can use a logger statement to see the params hash and try to change the hash to make it work.

It would be helpful if you post the params hash to see what you are missing

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! I already tried to find out about my parameter hashes and updated my question. It seems that, somewhere along the way between the contacts/new form and the actual POST-request, the customer_id gets lost.

Comment: You need to add customer_id as hidden field in the new form. something like this <%= hidden_field_tag("customer_id", @customer_id)%>

Comment: Using <%= hidden_field_tag("customer_id", params[:customer_id]%> I managed to get the customer_id field over to the new-POST-request. However, the join table is still not automatically updated by rails. I'm already contemplating doing it manually via an SQL-query because I just can't get this to work :-(  I'm almost sure there's something wrong with the way my controllers/models are set up, I just cannot put my finger on it. Any other ideas maybe?

Comment: From the hash you posted above, It seems that you are not using f.fields_for to generate nested fields for contact with respect to customer. Your generated hash should look something like params[:customer] = {:id => '260', :contact_attributes => [
  { "anrede"=>"", "name"=>"Test", "position"=>"", "telefon"=>"", "mobil"=>"", "fax"=>"", "email"=>"", "sonstiges"=>""} ]}. Play with this hash in console in development mode and see the development.log to see which tables are invoked

Comment: Actually, I don't *want* to use nested fields (I had that function working already), because I am unhappy with the functionality. Showing the customer data and then having a link "add new contact", which automatically opens a "new contact" form is much more usable (in my eyes) then having all the info on a single form. I'm sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Thanks.. You should have been clear of what you are asking. I have spend quiet a time trying to get your thing working.. Anyways.. If you foudn my suggestions helpful you should take time to vote,,

Comment: I managed to find a workaround based on your hidden_field technique: It may be very....messy, but at least it does what I want. I added: "sql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection(); sql.execute "INSERT INTO contacts_customers (contact_id, customer_id) VALUES (" + @contact.id.to_s + ", " + params[:customer_id].to_s + ")"  in order to manually maniplate the join table et voilà, I got the info I want inside. It may not be the best or prettiest solution, but it works. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: please convey your thanks by voting the sugesstion/answers helper you..thank u

Comment: I'm missing the rep to upvote your post, but I checked it as "accepted answer" because you essentially gave me the solution to my problem. Thanks again :)